# In Akka, how do I route responses from downstream actor to the correct upstream?

Tags: scala, redis, akka, actor

Newbie question: I am trying to have a single cache manager that sits between multiple users of the cache (= upstream), and Redis client (downstream), so:

```
Client A  -----> |                
                 | Cache Manager <=====> Redis Connection --(tcp)--
Client B  -----> |
```

The idea is to re-use a single connection to Redis.  I can send SET commands asynchronously, when responses come back from the redis client actor, how do I know which client to relay the response to?  Here is my receive method so far:

```
def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {

  case Store(key: ByteString, payload: ByteString, metadata: ByeString) => {
    // WIP: yes, I could batch these two here
    brandoClient ! Request(REDIS_SET, metadata_key(key), metadata)
    brandoClient ! Request(REDIS_SET, key, payload)
  }

  case Some(Ok) => {
    ???
  }
  ...
}
```

I could do:

```
case Store(key: ByteString, payload: ByteString) => {
  val future = brandoClient ? Request(REDIS_SET, key, payload)
  sender() ! Await.result(future, request_timeout.duration)
}
```

But, that's going to make this cache manager block.

The other way I can think of is to create multiple Cache Manager actors that refer to the same Redis client ActorRef, so that I can dedupe the responses that way.  Like so:

```
Client A  -----> Cache Manager A -----> |               
                                        | Redis Connection --(tcp)--
Client B  -----> Cache Manager B -----> |
```

Is this the only way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blocking, you could [pipe](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future) the result of the `Future` to the sender. The following example assumes that you're using the [Brando](https://github.com/chrisdinn/brando) Redis client:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.pattern.{ ask, pipe }
import akka.util.{ ByteString, Timeout }
import brando.{ Request, StatusReply }
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class Store(key: ByteString, payload: ByteString)

class CacheManager extends Actor {
  import context.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  val brandoClient: ActorRef = ???

  def receive = {
    case Store(key, payload) =>
      (brandoClient ? Request("SET", key, payload))
        .mapTo[Some[StatusReply]]
        .pipeTo(sender())

    // case ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify your message signature then you could always add something similar to an [http correlation id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_fields) inside each message.

Each incoming request would come with a [unique id](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), then you could keep an internal map of type `Map[UUID, ActorRef]`.  When you have the data to return then simply lookup the corresponding unique id in the map and send the data back to the referenced ActorRef.

Comment: Yeah, I am going down that route.  BTW, I am using this redis client called Brando, which will send me back just Some(Ok) when something is successful, so I can't really add anything there.

But, I can still have a separate actor for interacting with Brando, and route the response back to the right sender, with appropriate wrapping, so the sender can route the message upstream.